# Is $\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{1}{x\sin 2x}dx$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Is the following integral divergent?
>   $$\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{1}{x\sin 2x}dx$$

---

I've tried to substitute $\alpha>0$ for $0$, as it is a second type of determinant integral. But then I am left with a tough integral. The comparison test gives me no solution since I get $1/x$ which is divergent and so nothing can be said about my function.

Please. while writing Your answer, try to tell me what principles are You using and how.

Thank You

Comment: Maybe you wanted $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{x\,dx}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{K}{2},$$ where $$K=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall from elementary geometry that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x$$

for $0\le |x|\le \pi/2$.  Then, we see that

$$\left|\frac{1}{x\sin(2x)}\right|\ge \frac{1}{2x^2}$$

for  $x\in (0,\pi/4]$.

Then, we see that for all $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\epsilon}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{x\sin(2x)}\,dx &\ge \int_{\epsilon}^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{2x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{2}{\pi}\\\\
&\to \infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,\epsilon\to 0^+
\end{align}$$

Comment: @vilenc3 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Is it enough, that equivalent form of starting function is the \frac1{2x^2}, and by the P test for II order Improper integranls this function is divergent, so starting one has to be also?

Comment: The improper integral here is $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{x\sin(2x)}\,dx $$Thus, if the integrand is dominated by a function for which its improper integral diverges, then the integral of interest diverges also.

Comment: Thank You, that have helped me a lot!

Comment: Instead of $x\cos x\le\sin x\le x$ you could use the simpler inequality $\dfrac x 2 < \sin x < x$ for $x>0$ close enough to $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, indeed there are other bounds that suffice.  In fact, for purpose here, we only needed the right-hand side inequality.  The rationale for giving the left-hand side inequality was for completeness and also to point to an inequality that is introduced in elementary geometry.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. The integrand is a continuous function over $(0,\pi/4]$, a potential problem is at $x \to 0$.

By Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one has
$$
\frac1{x\sin(2x)} \sim \frac1{2x^2}
$$ then the inital integral is divergent by the comparison test.

Comment: In fact, we have $\frac{1}{x\sin(2x)}\ge \frac{1}{2x^2}$ for all $x\in (0,\pi/4]$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Yes, but when the initial integral is divergent, which is by p test, how can we determine that starting function is also?

Comment: @vilenc3 Thank you. We find it because we know that, as $x \to 0$, then $\sin(2x) \sim 2x$. Thus $x\sin(2x) \sim 2x^2$.